# Flask TypeError: Expected bytes

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get data from a table and response the result. I am facing this issue since the data is from a database. Below is the code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from table""")
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    data = row
connection.close()
return Response(
    data,
    mimetype="text/csv",
    headers={
        "Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=data.csv"
    },
)
```

While trying to get it, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Expected bytes
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Because your data is not `bytes`, it's probably a tuple. What do you actually want to output?

Comment: Data is expected to be returned in bytes

Comment: _What data_? You're making a query that selects all columns from all the rows in `table`, but what then? Do you want it as e.g. JSON? CSV? Just random arbitrary text?

Comment: If you see my question I have clearly mentioned, need to get the data as a response of flask routing method in CSV format. Please check the return type ```return Responsedata,
    mimetype="text/csv",
    headers={
        "Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=data.csv"
    },
)```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like this. I elided the `connection`-related bits, because they're specific to your database connection.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

# ...

# Instantiate a StringIO to buffer the CSV in memory to
sio = StringIO()

# Instantiate a CSV writer to write to the StringIO
cw = csv.writer(sio)

# Execute the query
cursor.execute("""select * from table""")

# Depending on your database, you could use `cw.writerow`
# before the loop to write the column names as the first line here.

# Loop over the rows returned by the query, casting each cell to a string
# before writing to the CSV writer.  You may need to adjust the `str()`
# invocation to format e.g. dates in a specific way.
for row in cursor:
    cw.writerow([str(cell) for cell in row])

# Get the StringIO's contents and encode to UTF-8 bytes
csv_bytes = sio.getvalue().encode("utf-8")

return Response(
    csv_bytes,
    mimetype="text/csv",
    headers={
        "Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=data.csv"
    },
)
```